# Web application vs. web services vs. classic application

Tags: winforms, web-applications, web-services

Please I need help.

I have project in which I need application which communicates with local DB server and simultaneously with central remote DB server to complete some task(read stock quotas from local server create order and then write order to central orders DB,...).
So, I don`t know which architecture and technology do this.
Web application, .NET WinForms client applications on each computer, or web services based central application with client applications?
What are general differences between this approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose your database directly to the clients, I'd recommend having a web service layer in between. Depending on the sensitivity of your data and the security level of your network, I'd recommend either a web service approach (where you can manage the encryption of data yourself, and without need for expensive ssl certificates) or a web interface (which might be easier to construct, but with limitations in security).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tomas that a web service layer might be good. However, when it comes to choosing between webforms or winforms I don't think your question includes enough information to make the choice.

I'd say that if you want a powerful and feature rich user interface and want to make development easy, Winforms is probably the way to go. But if you need it to be usuable from a varied array of clients and want easier maintenance and deployment, a web app might be best.

Answer (score 0):

First, focus on the exact relationship between these databases. What does "local" mean. Right there on the user's desktop? Shared between all the users in their office? Presumably the local quotes (you do mean stock **quotes** and not **quotas**?) could potentiually be a little out of date relative to the central order server's view of the world. Does that matter? I place an order for 100 X at price 78.34, real price may be different. What is the intended behaviour.

My guess is that there is at least some business logic and so we need to decide where that runs. One (thick client) approach is to put that logic on the desktop, the desktop app then might write directly to the central DB. I don't tend to do this for several reasons:

1. Every client desktop gets a database connection. Scaling is not good, eventually the database gets unhappy when the number of users gets very large.
2. If we need a slightly different app, perhaps exposed to a different set of users via the Web or whatever, we end up reproducing that business logic.

An alternative approach (thin or browser based) keeps the UI on the desktop, but puts the logic on the server. The client can then invoke some kind of service. Now there's lots of possible ways of doing that, a simple Web Service or Rest Service will do the job. I hope it's clear that this service-based appraoch addressed my two points above.

By symmetry I would treat the local databases in the same way, wrap them in services. However it's possible that some more complex relationship between the databases exists and in which case you might need the local service layer to interact with the central service layer.

I'm touting the general pronciple of Do Not Repeat Yourself, implement each piece of business logic once.